# setState() in multiple axios requests resulting in duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get some data from the github api, but I'm getting duplicate `<Card />` components in my output. Here's the code of my App.js. My card component seems to be working fine.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
// Enter some github usernames for "followers"
    followers: ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mnop"]
  }

  componentDidMount() {
// Use initial github username for mainUser
    axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/mainUser`)
      .then((resp)=> {
        console.log(resp);
        this.setState({
          users: [...this.state.users, resp]
        });
      })
      .catch(err=> console.log(err));

    this.state.followers.map((user) => {
      return(axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
      .then((resp)=> {
        console.log(resp);
        console.log(this.state.users);
        this.setState({
          users: [...this.state.users, resp]
        });
      }));
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <div className="container">
      {
        this.state.users.map(user => (   
          <Card key={Date.now()} user={user} />
        ))
      }
    </div>)
  }
}

export default App;
```

I assume I'm failing to understand something about the lifecycle.

Comment: Try using a better react key, `Date.now` isn't good enough. Don't use "random" keys either as you want the keys to persist through rerenders. Also, don't use the array index if you plan on mutating the array order. A user id or any other unique property from the array elements is what you want. Also, any time you are queueing state updates ***in a loop* you'll want to use a functional state update so they all enqueue and process as expected.

Comment: In your Axios response handlers (ie `.then(resp => { ... })`), you get the data from `resp.data`, not `resp` by itself

Comment: woowwww I have been battling with this for hours. Drew Reese that was a FIX. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main reason why it's failing for you is that you are using `Date.now()` as your key when rendering `<Card />` components.

Keys used within arrays must be unique among their siblings (in this case, `<Card />` components). This way React knows which items have been added/removed or changed. Plus, it prevents the unexpected behaviour that you are seeing.

Since the users that are returned from GitHub API include `id`, you could simply use that for your key. This way, React would render your `<Card />` components without duplicates.

Also, in your `axios` request, instead of trying to add the whole response object to your user's state, try and destructure the `data` from the response and assign that to your `users` state. This way you will get only the user data that you need.

Plus, it's a good practice to use the previous state from `setState()` when assigning new state rather than getting the current state. This way you can be sure that the `users` state will have all the previous users and the new user that you are concatenating.

Taken all of this into account, the state assignment could look something like this:

```js
.then(({ data }) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    users: [...prevState.users, data]
  }));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, `Date.now()` makes for a poor component key.

You could also tidy up your Axios requests, including using the response `data` instead of the entire response object. Something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  const allUsers = ["mainUser", ...this.state.followers]
  Promise.all(allUsers.map(user =>
    axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${encodeURIComponent(user)}`)
      .then(({ data }) => data)
  )).then(users => {
    this.setState({ users })
  }).catch(err => console.error(err))
}

render() {
  return(
    <div className="container">
      {
        this.state.users.map(user => (   
          <Card key={user.id} user={user} />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```